# Having trouble understand which table is count(*) actually counting when joining two tables together.

Tags: sql

If I have the following codes, which table is count(*) counting the number or rows in it?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM region r
JOIN sales_rep s
ON r.id = s.region_id
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: `COUNT` is counting _all_ records in the table resulting from the join.  You may convince yourself of this by running `SELECT *`, counting the number of records, then running `SELECT COUNT(*)` to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

It is counting the rows from your join query as a whole. It is the same as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(SELECT * FROM region r
JOIN sales_rep s
ON r.id = s.region_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is counting all records of the "resulting" table from the join. The number will depend on the type of relationship between region and sales_rep. Assuming your domain is that a region has zero or many sales_rep and that all sales_rep have one and only one region then the count will always equals to the count of sales_rep. For example:

```
regions: (id)            sales_rep: (id, reg_id)
A                        1 A
B                        2 A
C                        3 B
                         4 C
count(*) = 4
```

On the other hand if a sales_rep can have no region then the ones with no region are excluded:

```
regions: (id)            sales_rep: (id, reg_id)
A                        1 A
B                        2 null
C                        3 B
                         4 C
count(*) = 3
```

Or if a sales_rep can have more than one region then the result is the same as 1st case but you will have a higher count:

```
regions: (id)            sales_rep: (id, reg_id)
A                        1 A
B                        1 B
C                        2 A
                         3 B
                         4 C
count(*) = 5
```

I'd definitely recommend you to do a select * so you can see by yourself whats happening and then change it to count. Additionally please refer to this article to better understand joints: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp